# Shortcut to show/hide application toolbar in OSX

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm looking for a keyboard shortcut on Mac OSX to show/hide the application toolbar.

I was not able to find something about this issue... Maybe I was searching for the wrong keyword?

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on the Application. Some do not allow it (like Safari) while others do, but use different shortcuts. For instance, Preview uses ⌘B, whereas Adium uses ⌘⇧T. The best way to find out if an Application supports it is to use the Help menu to search for Toolbar.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make the shortcut more consistent across applications:

[image]

That works even in some apps that don't have a menu bar item for toggling the toolbar (but do have a context menu item for it).